# How can I do this table in C++?

Tags: c++

I tried to make a C++ algorithm to show me this:

```
1     1     1     1       1
1     2     2     2       2
1     2     3     3       3
1     2     3     4       4
1     2     3     4       5
```

And that can be to the infinite, depends by the cin number.

So I made this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    cin >> n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=n+1-i;j++)
        cout << j << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but this shows me another pyramid.

So, can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: What's the pattern? How can you do this by hand? Hint: use `std::min`. Clearly it's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 constrained by the row number.

Comment: "_this shows me another pyramid._" <- not a problem description. _What_ does it show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,i,j;
    cin >> n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            cout << j << " ";
        }
        for(int k = i+1; k <= n; k++) {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope, this is your required algorithm.

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks so much!

Comment: Ha ha. You're welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I did not seen that {. My bad!